# How to compare two NSArrays in ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a stored NSArray. How can I observe the changes of another NSArray and compare with the stored one?
It looks like:

```
RACSignal *compareArraySignal = [[RACObserve(self, arr) ...];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what how you actually want to compare these arrays, you'll need to Observe both arrays, combine their values and then map to a result via your comparison.

```
RACSignal *compareArraySignal = [[RACSignal combineLatest:@[
        RACObserve(self, array1),
        RACObserve(self, array2)]]
  map:^id _Nullable(RACTuple * _Nullable value) {
    RACTupleUnpack(NSArray *array1, NSArray *array2) = value;
    return @([array1 isEqualToArray:array2]);
}];
```

In this example, I'm just comparing for equality, but you can do whatever is needed in the map block

Comment: That's what I need. Actually I would use `zip:` instead of `combineLatest:` to compare each pair of elements in both arrays.
Thank you.